# $3\mid a^3+b^3+c^3$ if only if $3\mid a+b+c $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Prove the following equivalence: $3\mid (a^3 + b^3 + c^3) $ if and only if $3\mid (a + b + c) $.

My try:

I know $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = (a + b + c) (a^2 + b^2 + c^2 – ab – bc – ca) + 3abc$, but I can't seem to proceed from here.

Thanks all!

Comment: Try to show that $a^2+b^2+c^2–ab–bc–ca$ is not divisible by 3. Or follow the answers posted here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527300/prove-that-6-divides-nn-1n-2) is that, $n^3−n=(n−1)n(n+1)$ being a product of three consecutive integers is a multiple of $3$.

Hence $3$ divides $(a^3−a)+(b^3−b)+(c^3−c)$ for any triple of integers $a,b,c$. Rearranging the terms, we have that $3$ dividing $(a^3+b^3+c^3)−(a+b+c)$.

Comment: Thanks for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 8):

Very short with *Lil' Fermat*:

for any $x\in\mathbf Z$, $\;x^3\equiv x\mod 3$. Hence $\;a^3+b^3+c^3\equiv a+b+c\mod 3$.

Answer (score 3):

Compare $a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca$ with $(a+b+c)^2$

Answer (score 3):

By Fermat's Little Theorem we know that $3$ divides $x^3-x$ for any $x \in \mathbb{Z}$

Which means $(a^3-a)+(b^3-b)+(c^3-c) = (a^3+b^3+c^3)-(a+b+c)$ is divisible by $3$.

The conclusion is easy to derive now.

Answer (score 2):

- $1^3 = 1 \mod 3$
- $2^3 = 2 \mod 3$
- $3^3 = 3 \mod 3$

This means $x = x^3 \mod 3$ for any integer $x$. This also means that if $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = 0 \mod 3$ then $a + b + c = 0 \mod 3$.

Thus it is divisible by three.